# How call the function that is in my main.mxml app from a as3 class in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

i write a sound playback class that stop the older sound and play the new sound.After that i need an extra method in this class that trigger when the sound play is complete.I successfully achieve this, but i need to inform the main app (main.mxml) about the completion of that sound playing.
How i do that ? Thanks in advance.

here is my sound playback class.

```
package com.m2b.data
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.media.SoundMixer;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    import mx.controls.Alert;
public class SoundPlayback
{
    private var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
    private var sm:SoundMixer = new SoundMixer();
    public  var snds:Sound; 

    public function SoundPlayback()
    {
        // constructor function
    }
    /** call if need to close all previous sound and play new one **/
    public function playSound():void{
        // the StopAll method is used to close/shutdown all sound 
        // in that domin that are describe in that cross doamin
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
        // play the new sound.
        channel = snds.play();
        channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundcomplete);
    }
    /** call when the new sound is play without stop old sounds**/
    public function playAllSound():void{
        // play the new sound.
        channel = snds.play();
        }
        private function soundcomplete(e:Event):void{
            Alert.show('<<<< complete >>>>>>');
        }
    }
}
```

and here us the function that pass the sound obj as param to class and then call play sound method for playing sound.

```
//tahir - play the sound (close all previous sound and play new one)
private var soundPlayer:SoundPlayback = new SoundPlayback();
private function welcomePackage():void{

 soundPlayer.snds = loaderQueue.getSound('CV-welcome'+randomNumber(1,3));
 soundPlayer.playSound();

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some R & D on my problem i found the answer

That is you call the main application from any mxml component but in case of AS3 it is not valid.

i just made the channel class public and write the listener function in my main.mxml.

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this, is with dispatching and listening to custom-events.  You can [read more here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=createevents_3.html).  But essentially, you're creating an event listener on your main class, and dispatching a custom event from your sound player.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in your `main.mxml`
as:

```
public function soundDone():void{
    Alert.show('<<<< complete >>>>>>');
}
```

and then modify your `soundcomplete()` function

```
private function soundcomplete(e:Event):void{
    parentApplication.soundDone();
}
```